# Karate API : Round a number to 2 decimal point in Json payload Karate API

Tags: karate

I'm trying to pass a value from a key which is in e.g . "29.00".  The request I'm passing this value to doesn't accept double quotations around the value.  It's accepting 2 decimal points only and a number. e.g 29.00

The issue is when I use **parseInt(amount)** or **parseFloat(amount)** its drops the last zero.  So the value becomes 29.0 which the api is not accepting.

I just need the value to be in 2 decimal points so the trailing 0 is not dropped.

I have used JS functions like function(test) { return parseInt(amount).toFixed(2)} but it is not working.

A sample of code I have used:

- def reqJson = read ('Json/PaynowPayload.json')
- def amount = SearchResults.ratePlans[0].rooms[0].totalCost.amount
- def Newamount = parseInt(amount).toFixed(2)
- set reqJson.payment.amount.minorUnits = Newamount

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me say that in my opinion, if the server does not accept `29.0` and only `29.00` it is a bug on the server-side and Karate has done the right thing to surface this for you.

Anyway, you can always "force" a string as the payload like this, and also look at the [`text` keyword](https://github.com/intuit/karate#text):

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* header Content-Type = 'application/json'
* request '{ "foo": 29.00 }'
* method post
```

Even though the request log may show `29.0` you can verify that the above request does what you expect because the response will echo the request sent:

```
1 > POST https://httpbin.org/anything
1 > Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
1 > Content-Length: 16
1 > Host: httpbin.org
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.11)
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
{"foo":29.0}

16:34:12.445 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 1293
1 < 200
1 < Date: Fri, 02 Jul 2021 11:04:12 GMT
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 < Content-Length: 510
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{"args":{},"data":"{ \"foo\": 29.00 }","more": "..."}
```

So now it is up to you to create the JSON string required. Here's just one way, there are other possibilities (Karate 1.X):

```
* def temp = java.lang.String.format("%.2f", new java.lang.Double(29))
* def body = `{ "foo": ${temp} }`
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* header Content-Type = 'application/json'
* request body
* method post
```